# TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined error on node.js app run

Tags: node.js, express, eval, ejs

Hello I'm trying to get [`pdfreader` module](https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader) to work in node.js to convert PDFs into text format.

When I run it simply using command line like `node sandbox/pdf.js` (the contents below) it works fine.

```
var pdfreader = require('pdfreader');

var rows = {}; // indexed by y-position

function printRows() {
  Object.keys(rows) // => array of y-positions (type: float)
    .sort((y1, y2) => parseFloat(y1) - parseFloat(y2)) // sort float positions
    .forEach((y) => console.log((rows[y] || []).join('')));
}

new pdfreader.PdfReader().parseFileItems('lib/sandbox/book-eric.pdf', function(err, item){
  if (!item || item.page) {
    // end of file, or page
    printRows();
    console.log('PAGE:', item.page);
    rows = {}; // clear rows for next page
  }
  else if (item.text) {
    // accumulate text items into rows object, per line
    (rows[item.y] = rows[item.y] || []).push(item.text);
  }
});
`
```

When I launch it from my `express`-based `node.js` app, however, using `node app` I get the following error as soon as I include the module

`var pdfreader = require('pdfreader');`

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAgent' of undefined
    at detectSyncFontLoadingSupport (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/deemeetree/Documents/Root/InfraNodus/node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js:60:1), <anonymous>:42060:38)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/deemeetree/Documents/Root/InfraNodus/node_modules/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js:60:1), <anonymous>:42066:5)
```

It looks like the module that it's relying on, `pdf2json` is trying to get `eval` of some files and it's not working:

`eval(_fileContent);` which is the content of `pdf2json` files.

Anyone knows what I could do to make it work?

Comment: What's the difference in running it stand alone compared to running it in the server?

Comment: Is your relative paths correct here? `/pdf2json/lib/pdf.js` where is the inclusion of `/sandbox/`?

Answer (score 5):

The solution was to add this before including the `pdfreader` module:

```
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node',
}

window.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node',
}
```

I hope it helps others as I spent 2 hours trying to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks for having shared your problem and solution with pdfreader, Dmitry!  In order to save some time to other `pdfreader` users, I shared it on the project's README.md file: https://github.com/adrienjoly/npm-pdfreader/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @AdrienJoly gréât!